# searching log files with date time stamp using awk generates syntax error

Tags: awk

I need to search logfiles with a date time stamp format of 2014-04-01 16:45:22.084

I am piping from grep to awk because the log files have header line with the timestamp and then detail information and I need to just check the header line.

When I run the awk with a string it works.

```
    grep "2014-04-01" log |awk -F"\t" '{if ($1>"2014-04-01 14:02:41.213") print $1,$5;}'
```

2014-04-01 16:45:22.084 Generic_Remote_Exception

When I try to use a date variable I get a syntax error.

```
    grep "2014-04-01" log |awk -F"\t" -vDate= "`date -d 'now-5 minutes' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S.%N`" '{if ($1>Date) print $1,$5;}'
```

awk: 2014-04-08 09:30:31.061837000
awk:              ^ syntax error

Why is awk generating an error?

Comment: You have a space after `Date=` remove it.  If you post some more log date, I am sure we can help you to get all in one `awk` and get rid of `grep`

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead of `\`...\``.  Backticks are [deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) syntax, however, their use does not cause an error.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
awk -F"\t" -vDate= "`date -d 'now-5 minutes' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S.%N`" '{if ($1>Date) print $1,$5;}'
```

to

```
awk -F\t -v Date="$(date -d -5min +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S.%N)" '$1>Date {print $1,$5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v Date="`date`" 'script'
```

sets the awk variable Date to the output of the shell command `date` before interpreting `script`.

```
awk -v Date= "`date`" 'script'
```

sets the awk variable `Date` to the null string and then tries to interpret the output of `date` as it if were an awk script, hence the syntax error because `2014-04-08 09:30:31.061837000` is not a syntactically correct awk script.